# django tsstypie. order_by queryset

Tags: django, api, sorting, sql-order-by, tastypie

Here is my models.py

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    uploaded = models.DateField()
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment, null=True, blank=True)
```

And my tastypie's API resources, api.py:

```
class PictureResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Picture.objects.all.order_by('-uploaded')
        resource_name = "photo"
        authorization = Authorization()
        API_LIMIT_PER_PAGE = 24
```

As you see, I want my API page in order by latest image uploaded.

My error code is:

> Function object has no attribute 'order_by'

As usually I don't know what to do...

(By the way, `API_LIMIT_PER_PAGE = 24` is this in the right place?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `queryset` to:

```
class PictureResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Picture.objects.all().order_by('-uploaded')
        resource_name = "photo"
        authorization = Authorization()
        API_LIMIT_PER_PAGE = 24
```

`all` by itself it's just a method, but if you use it like `all()` it returns a QuerySet. `order_by` is a QuerySet method.

```
>> type(Picture.objects.all)
<type 'instancemethod'>

>> type(Picture.objects.all())
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```